# the linux kernel crash, how to resolve it with the backtrace?

Tags: linux, crash

The crash backtrace:

```
unhandled page fault (15) at: 0x00000001
trap_no:0,error_code:0,oldmask:4096 
arm[0xfffffffc (nil) 0x4002c3a4 (nil) (nil) (nil) 0xbeb192c0 0xa2 (nil) (nil) 0x40104158 ] 
fp:0xbeb19cfc ip:0x4032515c sp:0xbeb192a8 lr:0x4029f67c pc:0x4029f60c cpsr:0x80000010 default:(nil) 
PC 0: /lib/libc.so.0 [0x4029f60c]
LR 0: /lib/libc.so.0(nanosleep+0x40) [0x4029f67c]
   0: /lib/libtest.so(DebugBacktrace+0x46c) [0x4016843c]
   1: /lib/libc.so.0(__default_rt_sa_restorer+0) [0x4029d9ac]
   2: /lib/libc.so.0(__uClibc_main+0x228) [0x402e3cf0]
```

how to resolve the problem?

Comment: This does not look like a kernel crash, but an user mode app crash.  How easily is this reproduced?

Comment: yes, when run the app about several hours,it will crash. then this is the backtrace. but the function is not any of my app. why?

Comment: The crash might not be in your app, but in some other system software.  You might try eliminating (no running) all other software to narrow it down.  These functions are from your platform's libc, in this case the micro uClibc.

Comment: Another thing to try, run the platform for hours without your app running and see if it still crashes.